# How to install qubes on a mac with full-disk encryption?

Tags: osx, qubes, refind

I installed Qubes r3.2 on a mac without rEFInd; it installed but failed to boot properly, I just got grub, and when I tried to do - boot - it wouldn't work. Next I installed Qubes r4, it didn't install at first but then I did manual partitioning and it installed okay, but again would boot into GRUB. I then installed Parrot and the same thing happened, it booted into GRUB. I reinstalled Mac and installed rEFInd on there. And now I want to install Qubes r4. What do I do? Do I keep Mac on there? Do I install in the bootcamp assist? Do I need to manually delete mac, and then partition qubes? Won't that delete rEFInd? And I read that in order for rEFInd to work I need to not fully encrypt the drive, which isn't going to work for me; I must have full encryption.